# Matcher `toBeTrue` is not a function on Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I write a test with the following structure with framework Jest, in javascript. I receive the error `TypeError: expect(...).toBeTrue is not a function`:

```
it('should assert true', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTrue();
});
```

I do not know if the developers simply removed the matcher along the package life, but [codacy](https://app.codacy.com) complains about me using a substitution line `expect(true).toBe(true)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.toBeTrue()`](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/boolean/#tobetrue) matcher is provided by [jest-extended](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/) pakcage.

You need to install it and [setup](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/getting-started/setup).

```json
"jest": {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["jest-extended/all"]
}
```